# Why does my word scrambling program scramble the word multiple times instead of once?

Tags: java

I made a program that chooses 1 word out of 3 choices and scrambles that word. The problem is that it scrambles the word twice or three times (depending on what index it is on in the array "words"). For example, if the program selects "bubble" it will scramble it twice to "bbbelulubbbe". If it selects "camcorder", it will scramble it three times like this "croademcrdeaocmrrccmrecardo". I only want the selected word scrambled once. How do i fix this?

```
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Random; 
public class Scramble { 
    public static void main (String[]args) { 
        String[] words= {"hat", "bubble", "camcorder"}; 
        Random rand= new Random(); 
        int endNum =rand.nextInt(3); 
        for (int i=0;i<=endNum;i++) { 
            int alt = endNum; 
            if (alt==0 || alt ==1 || alt==2) { 
                String ChosenWord=words[alt]; 
                LinkedList<Character> lnk = new LinkedList<Character>(); 
                for (int j=0;j<=ChosenWord.length()-1;j++) { 
                    lnk.add(ChosenWord.charAt(j)); 
                } 
                Collections.shuffle(lnk); 
                for (int p=0;p<lnk.size();p++) { 
                    char addLet=lnk.get(p); 
                    String wholeWord=""+addLet; 
                    System.out.print(wholeWord); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: first of all fix your indentation

Comment: +2 for beautiful use of logic `j<=ChosenWord.length()-1`

Answer (score 2):

When you randomly pick a index you loop through the size of the index that you randomly chose.

```
for (int i=0;i<=endNum;i++) {
```

Meaning that you mix the words as many times as the index. You can tell because "bbbelulubbbe" is bubble scrambled twice.

First time: "bbbelu"

Second Time: "lubbbe"

So instead just set `ChosenWord` based off of `endNum` immediately after declaring it.

```
String[] words= {"hat", "bubble", "camcorder"}; 
Random rand= new Random(); 
int endNum =rand.nextInt(words.length);
String ChosenWord=words[endNum]; 
LinkedList<Character> lnk = new LinkedList<Character>(); 
for (int j=0;j<=ChosenWord.length()-1;j++) { 
    lnk.add(ChosenWord.charAt(j)); 
} 
Collections.shuffle(lnk); 
for (int p=0;p<lnk.size();p++) { 
    char addLet=lnk.get(p); 
    String wholeWord=""+addLet; 
    System.out.print(wholeWord); 
}
```